# How does %*.*d work in printf()?

Tags: c++, c, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("%*.*d\n", -6 , 7,20000);
  printf("%*.*d\n", 5, -6, 2000);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0020000
 2000
```

I don't understand how does `printf` interpret the  format specifier *** . *** ?

While in the first call to `printf()`,does the later **7** override the former **-6**? So that the size of output width turns to 7?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The argument to the `*` before the `.` is the *field width* and the argument to the `*` after the `.` is the *precision*.

Field widths are the minimum number of bytes that will be output as a result of the conversion; the output will be padded (by default, on the left with spaces, but left zero padding and right space padding are also options, controlled by flags) if fewer bytes would be produced. A negative argument to the `*` for width is interpreted as the corresponding positive value with the `-` flag, which moves the padding to the right (i.e. left-justifies the field).

*Precision* on the other hand has a meaning that varies according to the conversion being performed. Negative precisions are treated as if no precision had been specified at all. For integers, it's the minimum number of *digits* (not total output) to be produced; if fewer digits would be produced, zeros are added to the left. An explicit precision of 0 results in no digits being produced when the value is 0 (instead of a single `0` being produced). For strings, precision *limits* the number of output bytes, truncating the string (and permitting a longer, non-null-terminated, input array) if necessary. For floating point specifiers, precision controls the number of places printed, either after the radix point (for `%f`) or the total places of significance (for the other formats).

In your examples:

```
printf("%*.*d\n", -6 , 7,20000);
```

Here the field is left-aligned (padding on right) with a minimum width of 6, but the field ends up being wider anyway, so the width is ignored. The precision of 7 forces integer output to be at least 7 digits, so you end up with `0020000` as the converted field contents, which already exceeded the width.

In the other one:

```
printf("%*.*d\n", 5, -6, 2000);
```

The field width is 5, with the default right alignment; padding is with spaces on the left. The negative precision is ignored, as if it were not specified, so the converted field contents are `2000`, only 4 bytes, which get padded up to 5 bytes to fill the width by means of a single leading space.

Comment: +1, but I think it should be "characters" or "digits", not "bytes".

Comment: @unwind: I used the word "bytes" intentionally. It's not "digits" because width counts things like sign, radix point (for float), etc. towards the total, and in the case of a locale where the radix point is a multibyte character, each byte would count towards the width. Note that in the C standard, "bytes" and "characters" are equivalent; I avoid using the word "characters" because it's ambiguous to most people, due to multibyte characters. POSIX changed all the references to "characters" in the specification for these functions to "bytes" to avoid the confusion.

Comment: Thanks very much. I think I've found the key point, that is the *field width* control the output width with the default right alignment and padding with spaces on the left if fewer bytes would be produced, and the *Precision* control the minimum numbers of digits to be output.

Answer (score 3):

```
printf("%*.*d\n", -6 , 7,20000);
```

is same as

```
printf("%-6.7d\n, 20000);
```

This just provide a way for dynamic format.

Answer (score 0):

this is source code of printf in glibc

```
/* VARARGS1 */
int  __printf (const char *format, ...)
{
 va_list arg;
 int done;

 va_start (arg, format);
 done = vfprintf (stdout, format, arg);
 va_end (arg);

 return done;
```

}

as you can see printf gets parameters from va_list

here's another example, to show you how printf works :

```
/* va_start example */
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <stdarg.h>     /* va_list, va_start, va_arg, va_end */

void PrintFloats (int n, ...)
{
  int i;
  double val;
  printf ("Printing floats:");
  va_list vl;
  va_start(vl,n);
  for (i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    val=va_arg(vl,double);
    printf (" [%.2f]",val);
  }
  va_end(vl);
  printf ("\n");
}

int main ()
{
  PrintFloats (3,3.14159,2.71828,1.41421);
  return 0;
}
```