# How does calling printf() add numbers here?

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

I don't understand how this `printf()` call is working to add together two numbers. Does the `%*c` have something to do with it?

```
//function that returns the value of adding two number
int add(int x, int y)
{
    NSLog(@"%*c",x, '\r');
    NSLog(@"%*c",y, '\r');
    return printf("%*c%*c",  x, '\r',  y, '\r'); // need to know detail view how its working
}
```

**for calling**

```
printf("Sum = %d", add(3, 4));
```

**Output**

```
Sum=7
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does %\*.\*d work in printf()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17566886/how-does-d-work-in-printf)

Comment: It wouldn't work in openCL, because printf returns 0 or 1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, this is clever.

```
return printf("%*c%*c",  x, '\r',  y, '\r');
```

On success, `printf()` will return how many character it printed, and `"%*c", x, '\r'` tell it to print `x` characters (`x-1` spaces followed by one `\r`). Therefore, `printf("%*c%*c",  x, '\r',  y, '\r')` will return how many characters are printed, which is `x+y`.

See [`printf(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) for further details.

---

Note:

As pointed out by [@shole](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22008046/1004301), this `int add(int x, int y)` works **only for both `x` and `y` are nonnegative integers**. For example:

```
add(-1, 1) // gives 2 instead of 0
add(0, 1)  // gives 2 instead of 1
```

Comment: I don't think '\r' are printed, it is just carriage return to begging of the line, white spaces are printed for x+y times

Comment: @Dabo In `"%*c", x, '\r'`, `\r` is the character consumed by the 'c' in `%*c`, obviously it also is the character to be printed by `printf()`. `\r` itself is a white space character.

Comment: But it is not printed x times, it is printed only once preceded by x-1 spaces.

Comment: thanks leeduhem for explanation i have up vote all for full explanation and accept yours for quick reply and exact answer

Answer (score 4):

When passed to `printf` (or similar functions), `%*c` means you're passing two parameters instead of one. The first parameter specifies a field width, and the second a character (or string, int, etc.) to write out in that width of field.

`printf` returns the total number of characters written to the output stream.

Answer (score 3):

A number after `%` specifies the field width; so `%5c` will print 4 spaces, followed by the character argument, giving a total of 5 characters.

`*` specifies that the field width is provided as an argument to `printf`. So this will print one field of `x` characters, followed by another of `y` characters. Each field consists of spaces followed by a carriage-return (`'\r'`), so there shouldn't be any visible output. `printf` returns the total number of characters printed - in this case, `x+y`.

Answer (score 3):

i agree with leeduhem, it is extremely clever,

`printf()` return the number of character it printed.
For the argument, I think it is more easy to understand with an example:(Also you can see the width trick in [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/):

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int x = printf("%*c", 100, '\r');
    printf("%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

x is whatever value you set to specific the width (in the eg, it's 100)

That means the width you specific is actually counted and return by the `printf()`

**But I think this `add()` can only duel with positive numbers, if one of the number is <= 0, the method should fail, you may try `add(-3,-4)`, in my own machine it still print 7...**

Comment: Note: "A negative precision argument is taken as if the precision were omitted".